# Groupby aggregated time in equal intervals

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model with a DateTimeField and I want to run some queries so I can get sum of other fields, grouped by specific time intervals like: 5min, 10min, 1hr, 3hr and etc.
I also need the intervals beginning and end.
I need this queries for drawing some charts, with the x-axis being time and the y-axis being sum of other field like sum of count.

```
   count = models.IntegerField(null=False)
   time = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
```

Comment: For handling datetime data in Python i highly recommend `arrow` https://pypi.org/project/arrow/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, and I used raw SQL to fetch the data from the MySQL DB. The syntax of SQL should be different for Postgres but this might be helpful for your use case.

```
SELECT TIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(time, @@session.time_zone, '+00:00')))/interval_in_seconds)*interval_in_seconds)) AS x, sum(count) FROM bees_submission group by x
interval_in_seconds = 30 / 60 / 300 (5mins) / 86400 (1day)
```

Hope it helps!